# Is there a way to get the url (or site name) of an opened website in C#?

Tags: c#, silverlight

Is there a way to get the url (or site name) of an opened website in C#? I need to use this to monitor and log user activity on my silverlight application. Didn't come across any success with a 2 hour googling...

Comment: The page the Silverlight widget is embedded in?

Comment: @Simon : Not yet done with Silverlight but from the console I need to pass it to a silverlight form..


@ Igor : Thanks, but I am not familiar with ToString();

Answer (score 2):

[`HtmlPage.Document`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.browser.htmlpage.document(v=VS.95).aspx).[`DocumentUri`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.browser.htmldocument.documenturi(v=VS.95).aspx).`ToString()`

Comment: I am stuck with the following code and the commented area is for the form but no luck where the form does not show any thing...my console is also a mess with every type of link printed....I want to at least trim it down to the least possible (like www.google.com)